# Error: Use correlation names to distinguish them in INSERT INTO using SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
INSERT  INTO traffic_data_aggregated_lanes
        ( aggregated_speed )
        SELECT  product
        FROM    temp_aggregated_speed
                JOIN temp_aggregated_speed 
                  ON traffic_data_aggregated_lanes.ID = temp_aggregated_speed.ID
        AND traffic_data_aggregated_lanes.date = temp_aggregated_speed.datetime;
```

I have faced one error while i am doing the above query.

```
Msg 1013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
```

The objects `"temp_aggregated_speed"` and `"temp_aggregated_speed"` in the `FROM` clause have    the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

Comment: use aliases! `JOIN temp_aggregated_speed as tas`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, you may be trying to update a column on an existing row in `traffic_data_aggregated_lanes`, in which case, the syntax should be an update:

```
UPDATE l
SET l.aggregated_speed = s.product
FROM    
    traffic_data_aggregated_lanes l
    INNER JOIN temp_aggregated_speed s
      ON l.ID = s.ID
      AND l.date = t.datetime;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are self joinning, just use one different alias for each different "instance"

```
Select product from temp_aggregated_speed 
JOIN 
temp_aggregated_speed ON
```

change to

```
Select tas1.product from temp_aggregated_speed tas1
JOIN 
temp_aggregated_speed tas2 ON
```